DebugMon_Handler not triggered after configuring DWT (Data Watchpoint and Trace) to look for memory writes. (cortex-M33)
I am using the following code to configure the DWT(Data Watchpoint and Trace)  and test it in Arm Development Studio. When using a Cortex-M4 or Cortex-M3, it triggers the DebugMon_Handler, but when using a Cortex-M33, it doesn't. Does anyone know the reason for this?
#include "RTE_Components.h"                 /* This mechanism is the standard way to include */
#include CMSIS_device_header                /* the device header file, in this case ARMCM33.h */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-parameter"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wmissing-declarations"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wreturn-type"

void watchpoint_enable()
{
    CoreDebug->DEMCR = CoreDebug_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk /*enable tracing*/ |
                       CoreDebug_DEMCR_MON_EN_Msk /*enable debug interrupt*/;
    uint32_t test_variable;
    printf("enable watch points.... \n");
    DWT->COMP1 = (uint32_t)&test_variable;
    DWT->MASK1 = 0;                         // match all comparator bits, don't ignore any
    DWT->FUNCTION1 = (1 << 11)             /*DATAVSIZE 1 - match whole word*/
                     | (1 << 1) | (1 << 2) /*generate a watchpoint event on write*/;
    printf("watch points enabled....\n");
    test_variable = 5; //                   <<----- CPU stops after this line
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    watchpoint_enable();
}

void DebugMon_Handler(void)
{

    printf("Debug handler in action...\n");
}

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

Besides: I found out that cortex-M33 doesn't have DWT->MASKx registers, while cortex-M3 and cortex-M4 do.
